# Place Joomla module outside of index.php

Tags: php, joomla, module, joomla-module

I have a php page that is just a page I am linking to, from index.php.

When I try to use jdoc include to place the module, it doesn't work.

Should I do something special to make this php page a part of the Joomla template? Should I make it an article? Or is there just another way to load this module?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jumi/ and on it you can put the path of your php file.